# i got a problem with my script , it is said that startcoroutine does not exist in my context

Tags: unity, c#

here is my script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;    

public class powerup : MonoBehaviour {

    public float multiplier = 2f;
    public float duration = 4f;
    
    public GameObject PickupEffect;

    void OnTriggerEnter (BoxCollider other)
    {
        if(other.CompareTag("Car"))
        {
            startcoroutine   (  Pickup(other));
        }
    }

    IEnumerator Pickup(BoxCollider Car)
    {
        Instantiate(PickupEffect, transform.position, transform.rotation);
        Car.transform.localScale *= multiplier;    
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(duration);

        Car.transform.localScale /= multiplier;


        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, You should use `StartCoroutine` instead of `startcoroutine`. c# is case sensitive.

Answer (score 2):

It's `StartCoroutine`, not `startcoroutine`. C# is a case-sensitive language. Capitalization matters.